# In R how can I rename variables in Dataframe A with variables in Dataframe B

Tags: r, rename

In R I have a DataFrame A like this

```
          Var 
1         Apple_d1
2         Banana_d1
3         C_d1 
4         D_d1
5         Eye_d1
6         F_d1
7         G_d1
```

And I have a Dataframe B like this

```
              Var 
    1         Apple
    2         Banana
    3         Eye
```

What I want to do is to Rename the variable in DataFrameA where the first part of Var are equal to the variables in DataFrameB. So in my example I want the result be like this

```
              Var 
    1         Apple
    2         Banana
    3         C_d1 
    4         D_d1
    5         Eye
    6         F_d1
    7         G_d1
```

Because the Data is large I can not do this one by one. Is there a programmatically way to do this? Thanks? Pleases let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Please stop wrapping your code in javascript tags. Also, "with your code I get this" really doesn't belong in the question. Besides, it's unclear who you're talking to.

Comment: Sorry for that. I will modify my question. If I want to put a dataframe in my question where should I put it?

Comment: If you mean how do you enter the data without wrapping in javascript, some instructions are over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks In the end, it looks similar to what you had, just without the big "run code snippet" buttons at the bottom of each data.frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

For the updated question, try

```
idx <- grepl(paste(d2$Var, collapse = "|"), d1$Var)
d1$Var[idx] <- sub("_d1$", "", d1$Var[idx])
```

This will still build the logical index as before but afterwards, instead of taking a fixed substring, it will remove the `_d1` ending of the corresponding rows.

---

Here's one option. Build a logical index that tells you whether a row contains data that is part of the second data.frame and then use it to get the substring of the right rows in the first data.frame.

```
idx <- grepl(paste(d2$Var, collapse = "|"), d1$Var)
d1$Var[idx] <- substr(d1$Var[idx], 0,1)

> d1
#   Var
#1    A
#2    B
#3 C_d1
#4 D_d1
#5    E
#6 F_d1
#7 G_d1
```

For a better understand of the code, I'd recommend just running its parts separately to understand it step by step:

```
> paste(d2$Var, collapse = "|")
#[1] "A|B|E"
> grepl(paste(d2$Var, collapse = "|"), d1$Var)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> d1$Var[idx]
#[1] "A_d1" "B_d1" "E_d1"
> substr(d1$Var[idx], 0,1)
#[1] "A" "B" "E"
```

data

```
> dput(d1)
structure(list(Var = c("A_d1", "B_d1", "C_d1", "D_d1", "E_d1", 
"F_d1", "G_d1")), .Names = "Var", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
> dput(d2)
structure(list(Var = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "E"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Var", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i'm very new to R. Can you explain your code a little? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: In my original example it works perfect but I got a problem with your solution. I modified my question  Can you see why it happens?

Comment: Thanks for explaining your code. Can you tell me what do 0 and 1 mean in ' substr(d1$Var[idx], 0,1) ' ? Thanks And why I got Apple_d1 renamed as A with your code? Thanks

Comment: @user5601679, thanks for the feedback. The trick in building the index is collapsing the values to 1 single string by pasting with `collapse = "|"` because `"|"` is treated as a logical OR in R's regex functions

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `ifelse`. Assuming `Var` as factor. It checks if the first char of `A$Var` is present in `B$Var`

```
ifelse(substring(A$Var, 1, 1) %in% B$Var, substring(A$Var, 1, 1), as.character(A$Var))

# [1] "A"    "B"    "C_d1" "D_d1" "E"    "F_d1" "G_d1"
```

**EDIT**

For the updated question, you can try

```
ifelse(gsub( "_.*$", "", A$Var ) %in% B$Var, gsub( "_.*$", "", A$Var ), as.character(A$Var))

# [1] "Apple"  "Banana" "C_d1"   "D_d1"   "Eye"    "F_d1"   "G_d1"
```